# how to fix the button and text position in other large and small screen android devices

Tags: android

I have a problem to my android application. if i run my app in other devices with large and small screen, the button and text position of my application will change. i don't know what is the problem? please help me guys.`

```
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />


</compatible-screens>`
```

Comment: bro. i don't know the code for my problem. i am asking what is the code for fixing position for button and text view if i run my application in large and small screen other android devices. :(

Comment: You should paste your whatever code written in java. So it can help the viewer to decide which way is suitable and the best fit for you. Check my answer, I showed you in dynamic Relativelayout coz I don't know which type of choices you are trying to complete it with .

Comment: i post my xml code in manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Get screen width and height at onCreate() and set buttons' and images' positions and size dynamically .

```
int width;
int height;
public void getscreensize(){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();
}
```

Call it from onCreate() and set your buttons like that.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getscreensize();

    Button btn1=new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpmbtn1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/2,height/7); // (set size)
    rlpmbtn1.topMargin=height/2+height/50;// (set position vertically)
    rlpmbtn1.leftMargin=width/2-width/13; // (set position horizontally)
    rl.addView(btn1,rlpmbtn1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that android devices have different aspect ratios.

You wanting to place your text (or button) in the same position for all devices is unrealistic.

In the different situation, We always do different work to make our app look like it's intended.

Please tell me, is your `XML` file in layout and your java code in src.